# Active Directory - Raise Forest Function Level

Tags: active-directory

We have an Active Directory environment with a Forest Functional Level of Windows 2000. We have four servers that are part of this environment. My question is, when we raise one of the Servers to the highest domain function level, does it automatically populate to the other three servers?

Comment: Also, does this involve a reboot of the server?

Answer (score 2):

Before you can raise the forest function level to the highest level, you will need to remove all your older and unsupported servers from the domain.  Then, you can raise the forest function level, the change will propagate to the entire domain and therefore, only needs to be done once. After you raise the forest function level, you can also raise the domain function level as well.

Comment: Just a note, the _Domain_ functional level(s) need to be raised first.

Comment: How long does both steps take to complete? Would this bring the network down and does it require a reboot of the server?

Comment: It will not bring the network down and only takes a couple of minutes to complete. It's just a matter of bringing up Active Directory Domains and Trusts and right-clicking on the root and selecting raise forest function level. Do the same for Active Directory Users and Computer, but right-click on your domain name and click raise domain function level.

Comment: What effect does this change have on the clients? Do they need to reboot or rejoin the domain? Another question, all of our servers are 2003 so how did they end up with Windows 2000 Domain Functional level?

Comment: The clients do not need to do anything. The change is transparent to the end users. After you upgrade all your domain controllers, you still need to upgrade the domain function level. I imagine if you started out with all 2003 DCs you still might need to upgrade your domain function level.

Comment: All four of our Domain Controllers are Windows Server 2003. They all have a Domain Functional Level of Windows Server 2000. When I upgrade one of them does it propagate to all four or do I have to do each individually?

Comment: It will propagate to all of them assuming they are part of the same domain. If you have multiple domains in your forest, you will need to upgrade each domain.

Comment: Joe, thanks for your help on this. Just to review, I will raise the Domain Functional Level on one of my Windows Server 2003 to Sever 2003 level. It will propagate to the other three servers. Then I will raise the Forest Functional Level on one of my Windows Server 2003 and this will also propagate to the other three servers. Last question how long does the change on the Domain Functional Level take? Everyone says the Forest Functional Level change is very quick.

Comment: The change will take just a long as replication takes. If all your domain controllers are in the same site, then the change will take effect in a matter of seconds. If the DCs are in another site, then it will take whatever time is configured in site and services.

Comment: The change was immediate on both changes. I literally clicked ok and checked the other servers and it had already propagated to them. Thanks again, Joe.